# how to make a div overlap another div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make `top-firstsection` go on the top of `flex-firstsection`. Like  for it to stay on top of the red background section . Right now  It looks like it is a navbar with a white background. I tried using `position:absolute` and `position: fixed` although it does work it sticks to the top when I scroll down. I just want it to stay in that section. Any help?

```css
.top-firstsection {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-list {
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;

}

.login {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.register {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #0972D7;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.first-left {
  padding-top: 220px;
  padding-left: 171px;
}

.flex-firstsection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
background-color: #e8534b;
}

.first-left h1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sectionOne-textbox {
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1.05px;
  line-height: 52px;
  width: 80%;
}

.sectionOne-button {
  background: #1F8FFB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="first-section">
  <div class="top-firstsection">
    <img src="images/Group.png" alt="logo" class="logo-header">
    <ul class="nav-list flex">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="login">LOGIN</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="register">REGISTER</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-firstsection">
    <div class="first-left">
      <h1>Open marketplace <br> for ordering & purhasing <br> scientific experiments</h1>
      <input type="text" id="" class="sectionOne-textbox" placeholder="Discover new experiments...">
      <button class="sectionOne-button">GET STARTED NOW!</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images/firstsectionbackground.png" alt="main graphic">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: negative `margin`? Also please provide a [repro]. The code you provided is neither minimal nor does it produce anything we can actually see.

Comment: would `.first-section {
  display:grid;
}
.first-section>* {
  grid-row:1;
  grid-column:1;
}`be the alternative to position you look for ? live test : https://jsfiddle.net/jp5q20wf/

Comment: Hello, i have re edited the question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a negative `margin-top` to the second div. This will overlap then the first div:

```css
#second-div {
  margin-top: -10vh;
}

/* for demonstration purpose only */
div {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="first-div">First section</div>
<div id="second-div">Second section</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I have already re edited the post, i am just trying to move the .top-firstsection go over .flex-firstsection . The negative margin does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for that either put the `top-firstsection` inside `flex-firstsection` which make it as a part of `flex-firstsection` and then **redesign accordingly**

```css
.top-firstsection {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-list {
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;

}

.login {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.register {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #0972D7;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.first-left {
  padding-top: 220px;
  padding-left: 171px;
}

.flex-firstsection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
background-color: #e8534b;
}

.first-left h1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sectionOne-textbox {
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1.05px;
  line-height: 52px;
  width: 80%;
}

.sectionOne-button {
  background: #1F8FFB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="first-section">
<div class="flex-firstsection">
  <div class="top-firstsection">
    <img src="images/Group.png" alt="logo" class="logo-header">
    <ul class="nav-list flex">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="login">LOGIN</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="register">REGISTER</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-firstsection">
    <div class="first-left">
      <h1>Open marketplace <br> for ordering & purhasing <br> scientific experiments</h1>
      <input type="text" id="" class="sectionOne-textbox" placeholder="Discover new experiments...">
      <button class="sectionOne-button">GET STARTED NOW!</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images/firstsectionbackground.png" alt="main graphic">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Other way round is having the both background of same color like in below snippet making it same .

```css
.top-firstsection {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #e8534b;
}

.nav-list {
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.login {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.register {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #0972D7;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.first-left {
  padding-top: 220px;
  padding-left: 171px;
}

.flex-firstsection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #e8534b;
}

.first-left h1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sectionOne-textbox {
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1.05px;
  line-height: 52px;
  width: 80%;
}

.sectionOne-button {
  background: #1F8FFB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="first-section">
  <div class="top-firstsection">
    <img src="images/Group.png" alt="logo" class="logo-header">
    <ul class="nav-list flex">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="login">LOGIN</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="register">REGISTER</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-firstsection">
    <div class="first-left">
      <h1>Open marketplace <br> for ordering & purhasing <br> scientific experiments</h1>
      <input type="text" id="" class="sectionOne-textbox" placeholder="Discover new experiments...">
      <button class="sectionOne-button">GET STARTED NOW!</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images/firstsectionbackground.png" alt="main graphic">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Things that can be taken into look , if you want `top-firstsection` & `flex-firstsection` near to each other :

- Consider to reduce `padding-top` value of `.first-left` making both near to each other
- Can use as stated in other answer by using -ve `margin` to `flex-firstsection`

These are some of the ways you can opt for and remember if you want to overlap each other than content of other may be hidden under other which is not good for your website so try only to reduce space between them .

Last thing if you want to overlap each-other really then try this method which use `position: absolute` and `margin-top` property for overlapping

> Add decoration according to need this is only for demo

```css
.top-firstsection {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  width: 97%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 80px
}

.nav-list {
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.login {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.register {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #0972D7;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.first-left {
  padding-top: 220px;
  padding-left: 171px;
}

.flex-firstsection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #e8534b;
}

.first-left h1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sectionOne-textbox {
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1.05px;
  line-height: 52px;
  width: 80%;
}

.sectionOne-button {
  background: #1F8FFB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="first-section">
  <div class="top-firstsection">
    <img src="images/Group.png" alt="logo" class="logo-header">
    <ul class="nav-list flex">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="login">LOGIN</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="register">REGISTER</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-firstsection">
    <div class="first-left">
      <h1>Open marketplace <br> for ordering & purhasing <br> scientific experiments</h1>
      <input type="text" id="" class="sectionOne-textbox" placeholder="Discover new experiments...">
      <button class="sectionOne-button">GET STARTED NOW!</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images/firstsectionbackground.png" alt="main graphic">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello, I have already re edited the post. Sorry for the confusing question. I am just trying to make  the .top-firstsection go over .flex-firstsection .

Comment: @Tryingprogrammer changed the answer see if any is suited for you