# Trying to make div move to another div

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make it look like this [image]

However, it currently looks like this
[image]

As, you can see the top section with the `logo` and `register` have their own section. I want it to stay on top of the background image. I do not want to use `position: absolute;` or `position : fixed;` since i want it to say in its own section. I have also tried using a negative margin and it does not work. Any help is appreciated.

```css
.top-firstsection {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-header {
  height: 80px;
}

.nav-list {
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.leftandright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.login {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.register {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #0972D7;
  letter-spacing: 0.98px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.first-left {
  padding-top: 220px;
  padding-left: 171px;
}

.first-left h1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sectionOne-textbox {
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1.05px;
  line-height: 52px;
  width: 80%;
}

.sectionOne-button {
  background: #1F8FFB;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="first-section">
  <div class="top-firstsection">
    <img src="logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo-header">
    <ul class="nav-list flex">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="login">LOGIN</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="register">REGISTER</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="leftandright">
    <div class="first-left">
      <h1>Open marketplace <br> for ordering & purhasing <br> scientific experiments</h1>
      <input type="text" id="" class="sectionOne-textbox" placeholder="Discover new experiments...">
      <button class="sectionOne-button">GET STARTED NOW!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="first-right">
      <img src="firstsectionbackground.png" alt="main graphic" class="main-graphic">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try to give it ```position:absolute``` and it will solve without being fixed

Comment: "I do not want to use position: absolute; or position : fixed; since i want it to say in its own section. ". Position absolute stays in the same section if you want it to (if the section has position:relative)

Comment: With that html structure, it will be hard to get just the image to move under those links

Comment: If you use an image as a background, why aren't you using it as a background-image, instead of an image tag? That makes no sense? Place `firstsectionbackground.png` as a background in `section`.

Comment: @Pete he has to change some of his structure to work the way he want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a div overlap another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236636/how-to-make-a-div-overlap-another-div)

Comment: @Rana it does not

Comment: @GertB. that works, its just that in `nav-list` `margin-left:auto;` does not work. How do I make nav-list go all the way to the right?

Comment: @Tryingprogrammer what is the problem you are facing in it , you have to change some of your structure and redesign . Using `position: absolute` means it is not fixed , it is fixed relative to its container and move with container acting as relative positioned to the body

Comment: @Tryingprogrammer if you position it with `right:0;` it will be positioned right in the relative container.

Comment: @GertB. alright got it fixed thanks. How do i set this question to answered?